# html support for node mail module

Tags: node.js

I have installed node mail module (npm i mail - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail)

```
 mail.message({
  from: 'sender@example.net',
  to: ['recipient@somewhere.org'],
  subject: 'Hello from Node.JS'
})
.body('<h2>hello</h2>')
.send(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Sent!');
});
```

I'm sending html template under .body(). Its not parsing to html in the email.
Does this module doesn't support parsing to html format?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this, and it works. Put your HTML data with {subject,to..}

```
var mailOptions = {
    html: '<h2>hello</h2>',
    subject: 'Product Quantity less than 0',
    to: '*******' //(Production)
}
```

Comment: thanks @mehta-rohan. Tried the same. after receiving email, I don't see anything under email body.

Answer (score 0):

create mailOptions json and pass your html as mailOptions.html

```
var mailOptions = {};
mailOptions.to = mailTo;
mailOptions.html ='Your html Text Here';
mailOptions.subject='Mail Subject here';
```

Now pass mailOptions to mail.send funcction as below

```
mail.message(mailOptions).send(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Sent!');
});
```

Comment: thanks @Ankit for the reply. But, I tried the above, I didn't see any text in the email body. Should I write something in .body()?

Comment: this npm library is not working in my current node version so i am not able to fix this issue but you can use Nodemailer npm as @mehta-rohan. suggested it is provides easy and clean configuration